# Godot Won't Spawn Particles

Tags: godot

I'm currently trying to make an explosion when a node hits the ground, but there's no explosion. I played the explosion scene and it works just fine. I tried spawning a different object and it works just fine. I checked the position of the explosion and it's the same as the body position. The explosion shows up in the inspector but not in game.

```
func _on_Ground_body_shape_entered(body_id, body, body_shape, local_shape):
print("collision")
var scene = load("res://Rock/Explosion.tscn")
var explosion = scene.instance()
add_child(explosion)
explosion.global_position = body.global_position
explosion.emitting = true
print(explosion.position)
print(body.position)
body.queue_free()
```

Answer (score 1):

"load" isn't a thing, do `var scene = preload("res://Rock/Explosion.tscn")`